# EF4.1 Code First Add Entity with Related Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm using EF4.1 Code First. I can't get a very simple insert to save the related entity ID. The generated SQL always inserts NULL for any related entities. Example code is below. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? It does properly insert non-entity properties, such as strings. Also I have similar code in a DB initializer class to seed test data and it seems to work fine.

```
        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            ctx.Users.Attach(existingUser);

            // create item and add to context
            var newItem = new MyItem();
            ctx.MyItems.Add(newItem);

            // set related entity
            newItem.CreatedBy = existingUser;

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work with default configuration of your `DbContext`. One possible explanation that it does not work is that you have automatic change detection disabled, for instance if you have in your context's constructor something like:

```
public DataContext()
{
    this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
}
```

In this case EF would not detect the change of the navigation property `newItem.CreatedBy` after you have added the new item to the context. (`SaveChanges` would detect this last change if change detection isn't disabled.)

You can change your code so that setting the navigation property happens before you add the new item to the context:

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{
    ctx.Users.Attach(existingUser);

    // create item and add to context
    var newItem = new MyItem();

    // set related entity
    newItem.CreatedBy = existingUser;

    ctx.MyItems.Add(newItem);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should work with and without automatic change detection.

Comment: I did indeed have change detection set to false. And moving the code as noted above resolved the issue. Thanks for the help. I suppose there must also be some way to mark the property as changed? What about the case where your updating an existing entity.

Comment: It appears doing something like this: `ctx.Entry(existingItem).State = EntityState.Modified` is the solution in the case of an existing entity being attached.

Comment: @Barry: Be aware that setting the state manually to `Modified` causes a *full* update SQL statement: *All* properties will be sent to the server, no matter if they really changed or not. Often it can be better (performance-wise) to retrieve the original object from the DB and merge the changed properties into it. EF will track those changes and only sent an update command with the really changed properties.

Comment: Many times I know what is potentially changed before saving. Is there a way to manually mark individual properties as modified?

Comment: @Barry: Yes: `dbContext.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.SomeProperty).IsModified = true;` It marks `SomeProperty` of the attached `entity` as modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{
    ctx.Users.Attach(existingUser);

    // create item and add to context
    var newItem = new MyItem();
    ctx.MyItems.Add(newItem);

    // set related entity
    newItem.CreatedBy = existingUser;

    // Added
    ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newItem.CreatedBy, EntityState.Added);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If that doesn't work, change the line with:

ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newItem.CreatedBy, EntityState.Modified);

Added 1 line... Hope it helps.